# How can I establish a connection between a local Git repository and a Jenkins server, automate the job triggers,?

Tags: git, jenkins, repository, local

we tried to connect jekins server to local git but unable to connect ,also we tried different methods to connect & push code from local repository & to the local centralized git, but that also we hadn't got any solution please help us out.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup at work, and the two main obstacles were:

- network route (you need to confirm that your Jenkins main controller can contact your Git server, port 443 for https Git URL)
- a valid Git account: all our repositories on our Git server (Gitea in our case) are private.
  I have set up an account that we add to a "read-only" team associated with the repository we want to access.
  And I have added the credentials of that account in Jenkins, using the [Credentials plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials/), as described in "[How to Add GIT Credentials in Jenkins?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-git-credentials-in-jenkins/)"

With those two elements, I don't have any issue for my Jenkins to access and clone any Git repository I need.